# Change DateTimePicker Format different from Windows Format

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a already done a system that contains a lot of forms that use DateTimePicker.
Now i need to publish in another country with a different date format from mine.
I already did a search and i found a property where i can put a custom format.
But i don't want to seek all system DateTimePicker to put this property.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force a specific format for all `DateTimePicker` objects you have, you have no choice other than going through them and setting the values of `DateTimePicker.Format` and `DateTimePicker.CustomFormat`. The reason for this limitation is that objects are totally independent. NO change on specific object will affect another object (unless specifically expressed in your logic flow).

You might want to create a global application variable and reference it in existing `DateTimePicker` objects. This is a one time action. Later on you will be able to simply change the value of that global variable which will be reflected in all existing objects.

I assume (out of the question title) you already know that the default format is that of Windows, or more specifically of the culture configuration on the host machine. Deploying to another country will probably mean deploying to host running with other culture configurations (which will be automatically reflected to `DateTimePicker` objects in your application.

Please also keep in mind that forcing some people to use a format you are defining might be annoying. That is my case for example where I have the `en-US` culture configured on my machine but I live in Denmark. I will appreciate to see the date in `en-US` rather in `da-DK` (although for this specific case, the difference is not much, just days naming).

Comment: I feared this. This system is to large to seek all pickers. But if there isn't another way i'll do this. Thanks.